Magnetic force expression in COMSOL, what does the T stand for?
During a recent project I've used COMSOL to help evaluate the force excerted on a steel ball from an electromagnet. The formula used by COMSOL is:
\begin{equation}
    \textbf{F} = \int_{\partial\Omega}^{} 2\pi r\textbf{n} T\,dS 
\end{equation}
My question is about the term T: what does it stand for? I have not come across this integral outside COMSOL, so any help clarifying what the T stands for is greatly appreciated. Is it magnetic tension?
Thanks!

I found the answer. The T refers to Maxwell's Stress Tensor.
\begin{equation}
    \textbf{T}_{i,j} = \epsilon_0\left(E_iE_j-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}E^2\right)+ \frac{1}{\mu_0}\left(B_iB_j-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}B^2\right)
\end{equation}
I refer to Griffiths Introduction to electrodynamics, ch.8 for the derivation.
Alternatively https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_stress_tensor.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
